# TypeScript function with two types inference error

Tags: typescript

I'm intending `changeSelectedItem` to be one of two functions that have different types for its argument.

```
type Props = {
  changeSelectedItem:
    | ((value: string) => void)
    | ((item: { displayValue: ReactNode; value: string }) => void);
}

function Component({ changeSelectedItem }: Props) {
  const onChange = (
    event: SelectChangeEvent<
      string | { displayValue: ReactNode; value: string }
    >
  ) => {
    const selectedValue = event.target.value;
    changeSelectedItem(selectedValue);
  };
  
  // ...
}
```

But when using it, it's type becomes an intersection.

```
// TS inferred type of `changeSelectedItem`.

(parameter) changeSelectedItem: (arg0: string & {
  displayValue: ReactNode;
  value: string;
}) => void
```

Which causes this error.

```
// Error on `changeSelectedItem(selectedValue)`.

Argument of type 'string | { displayValue: ReactNode; value: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string & { displayValue: ReactNode; value: string; }'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'string & { displayValue: ReactNode; value: string; }'.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type '{ displayValue: ReactNode; value: string; }'.ts(2345)
const selectedValue: string | {
    displayValue: ReactNode;
    value: string;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A union of two function types results in a function type which takes the intersection of their parameter types and returns the union type of their results. If we think about it a little bit it's clearly necessary for type safety, but it can lead to some surprising signatures.

Consider:

```
type ExtractAndWrapNumber = (data: { num: number }) => { wrapped: number };

type ExtractAndWrapString = (data: { str: string }) => { wrapped: string };

// `(data: { num: number } & { str: string }) => { wrapped: number | string }
type ExtractAndWrapNumberOrString =
  | ExtractAndWrapNumber
  | ExtractAndWrapString;

const f: ExtractAndWrapNumber = (data) => ({ wrapped: data.num });

const g: ExtractAndWrapString = (data) => ({ wrapped: data.str });

const h: ExtractAndWrapNumberOrString = Math.random() > 0.5 ? f : g;

const r1 = h({ num: 42 }); // error as it should since `h` could be `g`

const r2 = h({ str: "Hello World" }); // error as it should since `h` could be `f`
```

As the above indicates, we need to provide an argument that meets the requirements of both possible parameters. Fortunately, it's straightforward in this case.

Consider:

```
// satisfies both cases of the function type Union and
// returns either `{ wrapped: "Hello World" }` or `{ wrapped: 42 }`
// which is to say `{ wrapped: string } | { wrapped: number }`.
const r = h({ str: "Hello World", num: 42 }); 

// use TypeScript's CFA to differentiate the cases
if (typeof r.wrapped === "number") {
  console.log(r.wrapped.toFixed());
} else { 
  console.log(r.toLocaleUpperCase());
}
```

Of course, it's not always this straightforward. Sometimes the union of two function types will result in an parameter list to which no possible JavaScript value could conform such as `(value: boolean & symbol)`.

If you encounter such a case you should reconsider your design. For example, if what you really have is a function that can take *either* a `boolean` *or* a `symbol` either use TypeScript's overload signatures specifying each possibility, or a function type that takes a union of the possible parameter types instead of a union of function types.

Example using a union type as a parameter:

```
function h(data: { num: number } | { str: string }): { wrapped: number | string } {
  return {
    wrapped: "num" in data
      ? data.num
      : data.str
  };
}
```

Example using function signature overloads:

```
// Note that the types in the actual implementation
// don't contribute to the function type, 
// there are only two call signatures for `h`
function h(data: { num: number }): { wrapped: number };
function h(data: { str: string }): { wrapped: string };
// implementation
function h(data: { num: number } | { str: string }): { wrapped: number | string } {
  return {
    wrapped: `num` in data
      ? data.num
      : data.str
  };
}
```

The overload signature approach is useful when one wants to correlate the types of parameters and return values. Since it defines two distinct call signatures, we don't have to use CFA to handle the output:

```
const r = h({ num: 42 });
console.log(r.wrapped.toFixed());
```

In your specific case either:

```
type Props = {
  changeSelectedItem: (param: string | { displayValue: ReactNode; value: string }) => void;
};
```

Or:

```
type Props = {
  changeSelectedItem(value: string): void;
  changeSelectedItem(item: { displayValue: ReactNode; value: string }): void;
};
```

---

Note that this isn't an exhaustive list of options.

There are a few deltas, and additional techniques that you can consider depending on your needs. For example, if you want to leverage overloads but have `changeSelectedItem` considered a property, you can specify a type having multiple call signatures as in:

```
type Props = {
  changeSelectedItem: {
    (value: string): void;
    (item: { displayValue: ReactNode; value: string }): void;
  };
};
```

And so on.

Comment: I'd say a union of functions is very often a bad idea, because you can't differentiate between the two cases in any way before calling the function

Comment: @decorator-factory indeed. That's what I was getting at and trying to explain. Since it results in element wise intersected parameters, you have to pass an argument that conforms to all cases. Sometimes you end up with such functions as the result of type manipulation types which contain them and do member wise operations. Anyway they aren't nonsense in every case but they're not typically what you want